# Connection to MySQL database contained in a CentOS server

Tags: java, mysql, database, vps, jsch

I've currently got a VPS with Centos 5.2-i386-LAMP server running. I've managed to get it all setup and created a MySQL database. I'm creating an Android application and I need access to this server. Also, I am using Java for my development.

This is what I've been trying:

```
package com.example.jsch;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;

public class JSchUtility {

    private JSch jsch = new JSch();

    private String SSHHostname = "123.45.678.91";
    private String SSHUsername = "root";
    private String SSHPassword = "password";
    private int SSHPort = 22;

    private String MySQLHostname = "127.0.0.1";
    private String MySQLUsername = "username";
    private String MySQLPassword = "password";

    private int hostPort = 3306;
    private int dbHostPort = 3306;

    private String MySQLSchemaName = "sqldb";

    private Connection connection = null;

    public void sessionConnect() {

        try {
            com.jcraft.jsch.Session session = jsch.getSession(SSHUsername,     SSHHostname, SSHPort);
             session.setPassword(SSHPassword);

             final Properties config = new Properties();
             config.put( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" );
             session.setConfig(config);
             session.connect();

                 // This is where the error comes. PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:3306 cannot be bound.
             session.setPortForwardingL(hostPort, MySQLHostname, dbHostPort);

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + MySQLSchemaName, MySQLUsername, MySQLPassword);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sessionDestroy() {
         try {
             if(connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }

}
```

I've come to believe that perhaps Java isn't the best for this type thing? If there's a better language for connecting your application to a live server, I'd like to know.

Comment: Have you check the permissions of your CentOS server over MySQL(port 3306)? What CentOS version are you using? and do you install a GUI for your CentOS or plain Terminal?

Comment: I don't have a GUI for my CentOS, it's just plain terminal. And I've allowed remote access, so it should go through. Right?

Comment: Yes it is possible, please run this script as **root**:`mysql -uroot -h [server ip] -p` and post the result.

Comment: Or to test the port:`nmap -sT -O localhost -p 3306`